# Is it possible to create bundle.js for ReactNative components using web pack.?

Tags: react-native, webpack

Is it possible to configure webpack for React Native components.?
And Import that component in React Native Project from the webpack bundle

Comment: This is possible with web pack please refer this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711749/react-navigation-is-failing-to-bundle-when-using-with-webpack/57956629#57956629][1]]

Comment: This is possible with web pack please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711749/react-navigation-is-failing-to-bundle-when-using-with-webpack/57956629#57956629

Answer (score 0):

You can use it through the `React-native-webpack` module. This is an example of configuration.

**install**

```
npm install webpack json-loader clean-webpack-plugin react-native-webpack --save
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

**Exmaple configure**

```
global.__PLATFORM__ = process.env.RN_PLATFORM || 'ios';

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    index: [
      'react-native-webpack/clients/polyfills.js',
      `./index.${__PLATFORM__}.js`,
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: `[name].${__PLATFORM__}.bundle`,
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    quiet: false,
    noInfo: true,
    lazy: true,
    filename: `[name].${__PLATFORM__}.bundle`,
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000,
    },
    publicPath: '/',
    stats: { colors: true },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Could you please help me with the commands to generate the Bundle file. 
Currently i am using "webpack --config webpack.config.js --hot --mode development" in package.json and budling using "npm run build"